# How do I Solve this Error in Filter function

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

When I try to use the code in Google Sheets

```
=Filter(NKBPurchase!N2:N, isNumber(Search(D2, NKBPurchase!N2:N)), "Not Found")
```

I am getting an error stating the undermentioned

> FILTER has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 947. column
>   count: 1. Actual row count: 1, column count: 1.

Please suggest how to solve this issue.

Comment: Could you share a sample of your actual data and expected results? It is difficult to understand what you are actually trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

According to the Filter function [documentation](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197):

> condition arguments must have exactly the same length as range.

Your first condition "isNumber(Search(D2, NKBPurchase!N2:N))" is ok because it has the same length as the range (first argument). But your second condition is just one single value hence not having the same length as the range, you could just delete this second condition and the function will work.

Comment: First and foremost Appreciete the Help / Guidance and Thank you for the same.As suggested by you the first condition is working but the second condition needs to work also, if you could suggest how to make it work will be of great help

Comment: What is the second condition trying to achieve? In your case you didn't put a condition just a string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to closeout the ranges.  Replace

```
N2:N
```

with:

```
N2:N9999
```

or another appropriate value.